# Using awk to extract string

Tags: awk

```
This message1(name:"hello";age:10;US);
This message2(name:"hii";age:12;US;sdkfjd;l);
```

I wanted to extract word between age: and ; to get 10. The position of this word varies in each line. So I can't use $columnnumber.
When I use this, it's not giving the required output.

```
awk -F'age:|;' '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **awk**:

```
awk -F".*age:|;|)" '{print $2}' File
```

Set the field seperator as 1).*age: (char sequence ending with `age:`), 2)`;` and 3)`)`. Then just print the second field.

**Example:**

```
AMD$ cat File
This is a message(name:"hello";age:10;US);
This is a message(name:"hello";US;age:10);
This is a message(age:10;US;name:"hello");

AMD$ awk -F".*age:|;|)" '{print $2}' File
10
10
10
```

Comment: That is | (pipe) followed by closing round bracket... ) is the 3rd field seperator as i have mentioned in the answer...

Comment: ok. If age:"10" and need to extract 10, then awk -F".*age":|;|)" '{print $2}' is not enough rite?

Comment: In that case, script would be awk -F".*age:|;|)|\"" '{print $3}' File ... But it should be consistent across the file... i.e. Some lines cannot have as age:10 and some as age:"10".

Comment: Is there a default option to print 0 if no age exists in that line with above command?

Comment: awk -F".*age:|;|)|\"" '/age:/{print $3;next}{print 0}' File . That is, for lines containing the pattern /age:/, print the 3rd field, for those without age:, print 0... You should have given all these at one go in your question :-) .

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more question. Is it possible to extract all keywords as above in single awk command?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to awk, if your grep implementation supports perl regex:

```
grep -oP "(?<=age:)[0-9]+" File
10
```

or with GNU awk:

```
awk 'match($0, /age:"?([0-9]+)"?/, a) { print a[1] }' File
10
```